# Add a drop down combo box into innerHTML using javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to add a drop down combo box with a drop down mega menu.This is my code

```
 if (trendsmega!="")
 { 
  var companymegaid=document.getElementById("megamenu-mlid-783");
  //alert("Found   "+trendmegaid.innerHTML);
if (companymegaid!="")
{ 
  var othercompaniesli=document.getElementById("megamenu-mlid-1185");
   alert(othercompaniesli.innerHTML);
   othercompaniesli.innerHTML="";
 othercompaniesli.innerHTML=  "<select> <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>    <option value="saab">Saab</option> <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option> <option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>"; 
}
 }
```

I am getting the following error

```
  missing ; before statement
    [Break On This Error]   

     ....innerHTML=  "<select> <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> <option  value="saab"...

   /drupal/ (line 1329, col 56)
```

Can anyone help me how to add a combo box with innerhtml using java script.

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of `'` instead of `"` in you code.. will remove error.

you code will be

```
othercompaniesli.innerHTML=  "<select> <option value='volvo'>Volvo</option>    <option value='saab'>Saab</option> <option value='mercedes'>Mercedes</option> <option value='audi'>Audi</option> </select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using string inside a string, use '' sign.

```
"<select> <option value='volvo'>Volvo</option>";
```

Or if you have dynamic values use

```
"<option value="+ saab +">Saab</option>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it like this:

```
othercompaniesli.innerHTML="<select><option value='Volvo'></option></select>"
```

OR

```
othercompaniesli.innerHTML='<select><option value="Volvo"></option></select>'
```